# Can I serve 2 APIs similar to StackOverflow using 1 web application?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

If my current API is located at api.foo.com/v1, with /v1 being the context path and all requests going to the API servlet like so:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I would need to deploy another application to make api.foo.com/v2 available.

How could I reconfigure my application/environment to field both of these requests or is it impossible? Could the application accept all requests and the v1 and v2 be servlet or RESTful mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create two servlets, one to handle each REST service?  Add this to your `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletv1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stackoverflow.Servletv1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletv2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stackoverflow.Servletv2</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletv1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletv2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: v1 is already the context path, so your method would result in api.foo.com/v1/v1 and api.foo.com/v1/v2.

Comment: Why don't you change your context path?